# asp.net localhost or ip issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, iis-6

This is my current situation:

- Im trying to execute a website that access to some files in my hardisk.
- Im into a network of a company with an ip.
- I have IIS 5.1.

This is the problem that im having:

When i try with localhost, there isnt any problem, but when i try with the ip of my
  network computer, i get "file not found", and the path is correct.

asp.net uses different users to access resources depending if the url is localhost or ip
  of the network?

Thanks in advance for the help.
Best regards.
Jose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set a binding in IIS manager for the ip-address that you are using.